# Продолжить итерацию с генератора

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, итераторы

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def C():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
c = C()
def F(j):
    print(j, c.__next__())
for j in range(5):
    Process(target = F, args = (j,)).start()
```

Как сделать, чтобы подпроцессы использовали один генератор C()?
Со следующей генерацией значения, а не начального.
Например этот код выдаст 0 - 1, 1 - 1, 2 - 1...
А реализация только с этого: 0 - 1, 1 - 2, 2 - 3...
Или подпроцессы копируют объект генератор и никак это не обойти таким образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, так не получится.

Это можно решить иначе, при помощи Queue.
Оставим генератор в основном процессе, а подпроцессы будут получать значения.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079667/9921853) оригинал ответа на подобный вопрос.
Код - оттуда, несколько видоизмененный.

iolock служит только для обеспечения красоты демонстрационного вывода.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
NCORE = 4

def process(q, iolock):
    from time import sleep
    while True:
        stuff = q.get()
        if stuff is None: break
        with iolock:
            print("processing", stuff)
        # Обработка значения
        sleep(stuff)

def C():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
c = C()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE)
    iolock = mp.Lock()
    pool = mp.Pool(NCORE, initializer=process, initargs=(q, iolock))

    for item in c:
        # Здесь будет блокироваться, если в очереди уже NCORE элементов 
        q.put(item)
        with iolock:
            print("queued", stuff)

    for _ in range(NCORE):
        # tell workers we're done
        q.put(None)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```